# How i make the image more bigger

Tags: css, image

All that content in the page have a padding about 36px and the image i wanted to be as far as padding

HTML

```
<div class="column" span="row"><img class="performance__image" src="asset/image/bmw-m4.png" alt=""></div>
```

CSS

```
.performance__image {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: it's unclear your question bigger to fit what a div or just to scale it double please give us more details so we can help

Comment: How big? You're not being specific. Do you want the image to be full width?

Comment: All that content in the page have a padding about 36px and the image i wanted to be as far as padding  https://ibb.co/gM3HVWS

Comment: OK, so that means you want the image to be full width till it reaches the padding. Correct? Can you please share the CSS style for .column? I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: .column[span="row"]{
    grid-column: 1/-1;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image needs a parent reference. Assign a specific width to the image's parent div, in this case ".column".

When ".performance__image" width is set to a certain percentage it'll check the ".column" width and then adapt accordingly. See example

```css
.column[span="row"]{
width: 100%;
grid-column: 1/-1;
}
.performance__image {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="column" span="row"><img class="performance__image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: Thank you,i tried to change the width but he extend over the page it's because my page have a preset and can make width more bigger